Harmonic analysis in our school's power system using etap
I am a student interested in learning about harmonic analysis in power systems and mitigation using ETAP. I want to start by modeling our school’s power system. From my research, I understand that I need the single-line diagram of the power system, transformer ratings and impedance, cable types, lengths, and impedances, and load types.
Regarding load types, do I need to specify each load, such as lighting, computers, etc., or can I group them together? Also, do I need to use a Power Quality Analyzer (PQA) for each load?
